# File permissions aren't APPARENTLY working the way I expected

Tags: php, apache, debugging, web, file-permissions

I am using hosting provided by [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com).

Root directory is: `public_html`
I set it's file attributes to `700` by using FileZilla ftp.
Also I set individual file permissions to `600`.

`public_html` directory has only one file which is `index.html`. 
Now even though I have set puclic permission to zero as evident from right-most zero in both `600` and `700`. Still I am able to view file `index.html` by using web browser [here is the link](http://blabla1001.net46.net/). Why is that? I thought last zero in `600` or `700` meant `public` would not be able to view file, what is happening now then?

Answer (score 2):

Now, I think this is because the file is readable by your Apache user and it is Apache that is delivering the files to the browser.   What is the ownership of the file/folder.   Can you put these secure files outside the web root?

Comment: I created files myself using FIleZilla so I think I am the owner. Is this right presumption?

Comment: Again, I'm thinking that as you upload them they will be given different ownership.   Can you see who owns the folders in the FileZilla window?

Comment: The username with which I logged in, in the filezilla, is the one which is owner of file

Comment: I still suspect my original answer is still correct because of how the server is set up but could not explain why.  The everyone zero would/should apply to other users on your server.